# Compute Power(x,y) code clarification C++

Tags: c++

```
int Power(double x, double y) {
    long long power = y;
    double result = 1.0;
    if (y<0) {
        power = -power;
        x = 1 / x;
    }
    while (power) {
        if (power & 1) {
            result *= x;
        }
        x *= x;
        power >>= 1;
    }
    std::cout << result;
    return result;
}
```

I am seeking clarification about this code. Here are a few questions I have about the code

1. When the power is negative where is it multiplying 1/(x*y)?
2. In the if statement inside the while loop it tests to see if power%2 == 0 but if it is not mod 2 then where is that calculation taking place?
3. If someone can clarify through an example like x = 2 and y = 4 and show how the program runs to calculate the power to be 16 that will be really helpful.

I am new to programming so trying to understand basic primitive types with these examples. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you do #3 yourself? Take a pen and some paper and write down what happens step by step.

Comment: #1 - if y < 0, you abs() the exponent and do the reciprical of the mantissa, then do the rest of the power calc.

Comment: This will not handle fractional exponents at all BTW.  Passing it in as a double is a lie.

Comment: Remember that x to a negative power is 1/x to the same but positive power. Then look at the first conditional.

Comment: Ugh - that function is just horrible.  I'd forget wherever you found that function from and try a different site.  It's trying to use the idea that x^4 == (x^2)*(x^2) and thus saving a multiply vs using a simple for loop.

Comment: Note: Know that [std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) already exists.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I tried and failed kept getting wrong answers. I believe i keep messing up the numbers at result *= x and x *=x so just wanted some clarity on that

Comment: You can let the program do the math for you - have it printf()  out `x` and `result` each loop and you will better see what it is doing.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan righttt?? I found the code in a book I am using to learn C++ and i was lost by their explanation but thank you for suggesting the printf() idea ill use that right now and check it out

Comment: @MichaelDorgan its not saving one multiply. Its rather `O(y)` multiplications vs `O(log(y))` multiplications. Actually I expect any decent implementation of `pow` to use this or similar

Comment: I should have stated 1 multiply at 4 entries.  Of course it improves as the power gets higher as you state.  My issues is the double to long long conversion, no overflow checks, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. When the power is negative where is it multiplying 1/(x*y)?

Nowhere. When `y` is negative the code uses  `power = -power; x = 1 / x;`.

> 2. In the if statement inside the while loop it tests to see if power%2 == 0 but if it is not mod 2 then where is that calculation taking place?

No it doesn't. The code does not check if the power is even. It does check if the power is odd:

```
    if (power & 1) {
        result *= x;
    }
```

What is left now is even and if you consider that `(x^2n) == (x^n)^2` then you will understand why the code continues with:

```
    x *= x;
    power >>= 1;
```

For example `power` was `5` then the odd power is handled by `result*=x;`, we have 4 left, and `x^4` is the same as `(x^2)^2` so we can coninue the loop with `power` divided by `2` and `x` replaced by `x^2`.

> 3. If someone can clarify through an example like x = 2 and y = 4 and show how the program runs to calculate the power to be 16 that will be really helpful.

You should take this opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. If you want to step through code to see what each line does: debugger.

PS: the code is almost "ok-ish". What is not ok at all is the mess about types. `double y` is assigned to `long long power` and `double result` is returned as `int`. All this makes no sense. The function does not correctly calculate floating-point powers. As this is just an exercise, I would recommend to use `int` everywhere and concentrate on integers for now. Last but not least, note that this is code one actually should not write, because someone did it already: [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: thank you and yes i am trying to install a visual studio right now so i can use a debugger. I been using repl it to run the code